# Condition statement in a select

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's what i wanna do

```
Select X, Y, if Z IS NULL THEN ( select something ) else Z
```

Basically I want to select the 'Z' if it's null I want to select another value, can someone please suggest a code example with a case or something that I can follow through it ?

Comment: if z is null, do you want to set a different value for it from the same table, or do you want to query a totally different table all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select X, Y, NVL(Z, showThis) as Z
```

will return `showThis` if `Z` is null in **ORACLE**

```
Select X, Y, ISNULL(Z, showThis) as Z
```

will return `showThis` if `Z` is null in **SQL-SERVER**

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `coalesce()`?

```
Select X, Y,
       coalesce(z, <something else>) as z
```

Comment: basically if the user manually didnt choose a Z i have to select it based on certain criteria so i coalesce isn't the case here

Comment: @Aziz - your question is rather unclear. You're more likely to get a timely answer if you provide some detail, perhaps including sample data (and user input) with required output derived from that sample.

Comment: @APC i was unable to provide code because it's confidential and the query is really large , and what i was asking is only for a subquery so  i just simplified to get to the point of what i wanna do ,  but thank you man , the other solution with NVL helped, it's the same as coalesce though

Answer (score 0):

Choose with CASE:

```
select 
  X, Y, 
  case 
    when Z is null then (select something)
    else (select something else)
  end as col
from tablename
```